# If d, e are equivalent metrics on M, and T is a subset of M show that (M, d) is totally bounded iff (M, e) is totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My thought was to see if x is in the union of the open balls that cover (M, d) then to see if x is in the union of the balls under (M, e) If it isn't I wanted to try and split the balls in (M,d) until x was in a ball in (M,e). Is this totally wrong? Is there a better way to do this problem?

Comment: What is your definition of two metrics being "equivalent"? Does this mean that there are positive constants $c,C$ such that $cd \leq e \leq Cd$?

Comment: The question doesn't specify strong equivalence, just that the metrics generate the same open sets

Answer (score 0):

It’s not in general true if $d$ and $e$ are merely topologically equivalent. Let $M=\Bbb R$, let $d$ be the usual metric on $M$, and let $e(x,y)=\left|\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y\right|$ for $x,y\in M$. $\langle M,d\rangle$ is complete but not compact, so it can’t be totally bounded. $\langle M,e\rangle$, however, *is* totally bounded: show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $x>0$ such that the complement of $B_e(x,\epsilon)\cup B_e(-x,\epsilon)$ is compact.